# How to set Neo4j auto start when booting?

Tags: neo4j, operating-system, redhat

I want to start my Neo4j service when booting, and my system environment is **Redhat**.

I add below text on `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, but it is not working

```
/opt/neo4j/bin/neo4j start
```

But it works for MongoDB...

```
/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the Neo4j reference for Linux installation. You can find it here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-installation.html#_linux_service

We have an installer script that will configure Neo4j to startup at system boot `$ /path/to/neo4j-community-2.1.4/bin/neo4j-installer install`

First remove the text you've added from `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` to make sure there aren't any conflicts.

You can also use our debian package installation to automatically download, install, and configure Neo4j as a service on Linux.

That information can be found here: http://debian.neo4j.org/